# Change definition: How to week start on Sunday and end on Saturday in SSAS Time Dimension

Tags: time, ssas, business-intelligence, olap, dimension

Hello How can I set the definition of a week in my Time dimension in SSAS?
Now it starts on Monday ends on Sunday.
The week must start on Sunday and end on Saturday.
I know there is an option when creating new one
BUT
Do I need to create new one or is it possible to change it in current Time dimension?

Comment: if your current dimension references a table, then you need to update the table.   If it is a built-in time dimension, I think you will have to drop and re-create it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, when creating the Time dimension if you had specified a source system to create the table to then that table could be updated manually.

In either case it would likely be easier to drop and re-create the table. As the business key column is the stripped down date field, provided that column is referenced in your fact tables, this should be streamlined in re-processing.